# How to throw `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` manually in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to throw `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` in my code, but `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` has single constructor:

```
public DbUpdateConcurrencyException(
      [NotNullAttribute] string message, 
      [NotNullAttribute] IReadOnlyList<IUpdateEntry> entries)
```

I pass `null` in second parameter but as `[NotNullAttribute]` says, it can't be null.
In my try-catch code i just catch the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and i don't mind its properties (Message or ...).

Is there any way to throw and instance from this class out of the box?
I know i can make a custom Exception but i'd rather DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions. I dont belive you'll be able to catch an exception thats not an extension of Exception.Another method for custom exceptions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/agileer/2013/05/17/the-correct-way-to-code-a-custom-exception-class/

Comment: You can pass an empty list and call a method `AsReadonly` like this : `new List<IUpdateEntry>().AsReadonly()`. But i'm not sure it is the right way to throw that it that way. Because It gives the exception handler an option to do something about entries.

Comment: @jawad, DbUpdateConcurrencyException extends DbUpdateException and DbUpdateException extends Exception. Anyway i think you are right, it's better to make a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you are running [EF core 2.2 or below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbupdateconcurrencyexception?view=efcore-2.2), because the overloads you are looking for [have been introduced in ef core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbupdateconcurrencyexception?view=efcore-3.0). Therefore one answer will be upgrade to EF core 3.0 or newer,

If this is not an option, you can define your custom exception in the interim (I understand you'd rather avoid it but that's probably the cleanest way around it):

```
public class MyDbUpdateConcurrencyException : DbUpdateException
{
    public MyDbUpdateConcurrencyException(string message) : base(message, (Exception)null)
    {
    }
}
```

**UPD** As it's been pointed out in comments you can target different versions of .net core runtime with your current EF. I just wanted to point out that upgrading to EF core 3.0 might be tricky due to [a few breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) it introduced, therefore passing an empty list (as *Erik Philips* suggests) will likely be a more fitting solution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass in a list with a null entry.

[Working DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TMw6M5)

```
// @nuget: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -version 2.2
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update;                 
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException("message"
          , new List<IUpdateEntry> { null }  );
    }
}
```

Comment: DotNetFiddle users .net core 3.1. OP's clearly on older version.

Comment: It doesn't matter what version of .Net the compiler uses, it matter what version the assembly containing `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is, which is in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` assembly, and I loaded 2.2.