# Generate UnitTest that throws a DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a test in .Net 7EFCore to generate a DbUpdateConcurrencyException but not succeding in doing that. Basically trying to modify it using different context instances. Apparantly there is something I have misunderstood, why does this not throw an exception when changes have been made in a second context and I then try to modify and save it with the first again? What is the correct way of writing a test for this? The goal is to be able to test implementation of handling of concurrency issues so just throwing the exception is not enough, I want to get it into a state where there are changes and I get an error message like Modified Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Xunit;
namespace UnitTests;

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public virtual DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyObject>(entity =>  entity.ToTable("MyObject"));
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            // Implement handling
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ExceptionTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task DbUpdateConcurrencyExceptionTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "SaveChangesAsyncTest")
            .Options;

        await using var context = new MyContext(options);
        var myObject = new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "name when added" };
        context.MyObjects.Add(myObject);
        var result = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        // Modify the object using a new context instance
        await using var context2 = new MyContext(options);
        var myObject2 = await context2.MyObjects.FindAsync(myObject.Id);
        myObject2.Name = "New name";
        await context2.SaveChangesAsync();
        // Modify the original object using the original context instance
        myObject.Name = "Renamed again";
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        // Modify the same entity from the second context instance
        myObject2.Name = "Changed by second context";
        await context2.SaveChangesAsync();
        // Try to save the changes to the first context instance, which should result in a DbUpdateConcurrencyException
        myObject.Name = "Changed by first context";
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>(() => context.SaveChangesAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to throw \`DbUpdateConcurrencyException\` manually in .net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345880/how-to-throw-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-manually-in-net-core)

Comment: It does not. I need my entities to be in a conflicting state so i can correctly merge the changes and save a correct version. Just throwing the exception does not get my entities in the that state.

Comment: The entity should have a concurrency token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417945/861716

Comment: Perhaps they should, but I have never used a concurrency token and I can still get that exception on entries that does not have a concurrency token. So it should be possible to generate that error without one?

Comment: Of course you can. But EF won't do it unless you implement optimistic concurrency.

Comment: I too remember a time when a concurrency token wouldn't be used, but only as a stop-gap, because it was too expensive. Without a concurrency token EF Core would have to compare all the properties when saving to find any changes. That was always a bad idea.  The *current* documentation sounds like a concurrency token is a hard requirement. I don't remember the section about "application generated" tokens at all

Comment: I remember that I was actually hitting this exception even within a single DbContext, when I was mostly updating the entities with normal methods, but added a single direct update to the database via `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw`. Maybe try that too, to artificially create a discrepancy between the EF context state and the actual database state?

Comment: Note that I was _deleting_ the entries in my code. If you try to update an entity, but delete it in the DB via `ExecuteSqlRaw`, you most surely will hit this exception. If you are only updating the entities, it might actually be fine. In your code specifically, I would expect EF to issue one `INSERT` to add the object, one `SELECT` to get it back in the second context, and then a series of `UPDATE`'s - but the latter wouldn't normally try to check the old value of the object's fields in the DB, so no exception occurs.

Comment: My goal is to generate an update that gives me the "Modified Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. "

I tried Deleting the entity and then do an update, that give me the exception, but the error is "Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store." and the error handling would be a bit different for the case when the entity does not exist.

Comment: Why is it so important for you to see this exception raised? I don't understand the urge while at the same time you seem wary of implementing optimistic concurrency properly.

Comment: So I see the error logs from the application that I get this error every once in a while and I want to implement code for accurately handling it. If I can't accurately reproduce it, it is hard to write tests for making sure my code works as expected if I can't reproduce the problem in a test.

Comment: It would heave helped to know the reason why you want to raise it. A better question would have been: why do I see this error? Also, the error *is* thrown if you update a record that you have in memory but is deleted in the mean time. The message may be different, but it is a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

Comment: Not easy to think about everything when asking questions. :)
I want to raise it to be able to implement handling of the case that occurs that gives me the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0. I know deletion and updating of entities happen when the error occur, but what I don't know is why i'm getting a "Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store.'" when testing locally. The exception may be the same but I assume there are differences since the messages are different.

Answer (score 2):

The next piece of code will throw a DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

```
using var db = new MyContext();
var obj = db.MyObjects.First();
obj.Name = "new value";


using var db2 = new MyContext();
var obj2 = db2.MyObjects.First();
db2.MyObjects.Remove(obj2);
db2.SaveChanges();


db.SaveChanges();
```

In real code, this can happen when one client deletes an entity that another client is currently working with.

Comment: I'd also add `ORDER BY`, otherwise the `First()` might be non-deterministic depending on the database used.

Comment: Any idea why I would get a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 when I see it happening in the logs and getting a Attempted to update or delete an entity that does not exist in the store.'
when trying to write a test for it?